# How to capture and log or a toast event at the state of "Do you want to install this application"

Tags: android

Can I capture the event before the application is being installed, where it shows the permissions that application needs. How can I write the broadcast receiver to it?

I want to make a toast when an external Google Play application prompt
 **Do you want to install this application** and show "permissions"?

Can I do the same for Google play applications when the user press
     accept and download?

eg: Toast:"You are about to install" + app name (derived from the apk file)